# Как сделать нормальное логарифмирование в гистограмме

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Я хочу начертить гистограмму, используя библеотекн plotly - csv я прикреплю ниже, как и код - и при желаю логарифмировать получивышийся график. НО возникает проблема в том, что ось х на графике, совершенно не соответствует логарифмической шкале (должны быть метки поставлены на кратных длинах, типа 1,10,100 и т.д.), да и гистограмма не соотвествует дейстивительности: у меня мода распределения находиться на 30, а на графике на 44(да, если навести мышку на ячейку с модой, то отобразиться 30, но если провести мысленную прямую вниз - получим 44). Помогите, пожалуйста, что у меня в коде неправильно, что завставляет гистограмму строиться по не существующим данным, так еще и без логарифмирования, хотя в коде, я установил ясно log_x = True. Код, как я сказал прикреплю ниже, гистограмму в виде фото - тоже
Вот ссылка на ксв - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kkRZog0zvNHd0ll6D0_a5LS95Hrhz-GZ/view?usp=sharing

```
import pandas
import plotly.express as px

data_exp = pd.read_csv('DATA\exp_1.csv')

age_gis_log = px.histogram(
    data_frame=data_exp,
    height=300,
    width=900,
    x = 'Возраст',
    log_x=True    
)
age_gis_log.show()
```

[image: Это неправильно начертенная гистограмма]

Comment: Импорты в код добавьте. Хорошо бы ещё сами данные как-то показать или куда-то выложить.

Comment: Похоже на какой-то баг в `plotly`. Там и другие баги с гистограммами есть, они обсуждаются, а именно этого обсуждение не нашёл я что-то. Видимо, только править как-то лейблы на шкале `x`, не знаю, как это в `plotly` делается.

Comment: я не совсем понял: зачем вам логарифмическая шкала по x? у вас же там возраст указан.

Comment: @strawdog Для данных с длинным "хвостом" попробовать логарифм при рисовании их в принципе логично. Хотя для возраста смысла не так много, как для "цены дома", например )

Comment: strawdog как уже скали потому что, у меня на графике логнормальное распределение и его хорошо бы было отнормалить, и да, как уже правильно заметили, и как вы собтсвенно тоже,  к возрасту наверное не стоило логарифмирование делать, но так или иначе, это проблема plotly мне бы тоже в дальнейшем мешала

Comment: @TailsMan это действительно проблема plotly - отсутствие имплементации логарифмической шкалы по оси х. Зато по y он работает - можете попробовать. В вашем случае можно порекомендовать получить данные гистограммы через matplotlib.pyplot или numpy и отрисовать их уже с помощью px.bar

Comment: strawdog спасибо большое, только как это получить данные, координаты вершин, и ну, а как это сделать? И тогда разве ось х будет показывать не же уже отлогорифмированные значения, а не реальные, которые и требовалось вывести, То есть вместо 2о лет в базе данных, ln(20). Я думал, что можно просто значения оси икс поменять, вы видимо про это и говорите, но я не понял, если честно, как это сделать